# Number formatting, remove thousands separator

Tags: javascript, internationalization, number-formatting

I wish to format a number so that it has "leading zeros" (thus string is always equal length). - While I could as backup do this manually I wish to use the best option. - As a standard format syntax (like pythons `"{0:4d}".format(number)` ) seems to be unavailable, the next best is to use the internationalization library?

I've tried doing this in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f4202ne3/1/

```
let fmt = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', 
  {minimumIntegerDigits: 4,
  maximumFractionDigits: 0
});
m = 1;
n = 5001

console.log(m.toString(), fmt.format(m)) //"0001"
console.log(n.toString(), fmt.format(n)) ///"5000"
```

However this displays "5,000" and "0,001". How do I set the thousands separator to a value (`''`)?

Comment: See `NumberFormat` `options`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simply set the `useGrouping` option to `false`

```
let fmt = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  minimumIntegerDigits: 4,
  maximumFractionDigits: 0,
  useGrouping: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.pad` string method (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)

```
"1231".padStart(8,0)//00001231
"131".padStart(8,0)//00000131
```

Comment: while this solves the direct problem, I still wish to know how to set the thousands separator. (Otherwise I'd have this problem in the near future since I'd use it anyways to format the text to currencies for my output fields)